# GNU parallel + gunzip (or 7z, or bsdtar, or unzip): extract every "archivename.zip" into (to-be-created) its "archivename" subfolder

Tags: zip, gnu-parallel, 7z, gunzip

As in title. I've got a lot of ZIP archives that I want to extract.

All archives have their own unique name.

All archives contain **files only** (inside archives there are **NOT** folder(s) at all: no parent / main folder).

I'd like to process all these ZIP archives via GNU parallel.

To sum up:

- `archivename(s).zip` has **NOT** folder(s) inside
- extract content of `archivename(s).zip` into `archivename(s)/` folder (this folder needs to be created!)
- **keep** `archivename(s).zip` after extracting it
- repeat this for all the ZIP `archivename(s).zip`

I was wondering about what utility fits best ZIP extraction: gunzip? unzip? bsdtar? 7z?

P. S.: *I'd like to take advantage of GNU parallel for speeding up the whole operation (I'm using SATA SSD devices)*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Removing file extension when processing files](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#example-removing-file-extension-when-processing-files):

```bash
    parallel 'mkdir {.} && cd {.} && unzip ../{}' ::: *.zip
```

Comment: shame on me!!! If only I had read the manual... :p The answer was there: https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#EXAMPLE:-Removing-file-extension-when-processing-files  Thanks @Ole Tange for your precious software!! ;)